# Check which collider trigger in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### Context

I'm developing an `AbstractAliveEntity`, which have basically three functions:

- **Sight**: Detect interactable objects. (Collider + Raycast)
- **Detection**: Detect anothers `AbstractAliveEntities` (Collider + Raycast)
- **Hearing**: Hear noises (Collider)

Currently i'm creating via script empty gameObjects with these colliders.

### What i want

I want to know which collider was trigger in `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit`

### Code

Creating the Sphere collider

```cs
private void Start() {

        // Creating empty gameObject
        sightGameObject = new GameObject("Sight");
        sightGameObject.transform.parent = transform;
        sightGameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // Add Component Sphere
        _sightInteractable = sightGameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();

//        _sightInteractable = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        _sightInteractable.radius = radiusInteractableDetection;
        _sightInteractable.isTrigger = true;
}
```

Detecting

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

        // How can i detect which collider was?? this.gameObject = "Player" (i want "Sight")

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "which collider"? `other` is the collider that entered the trigger. It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes. `other` give me the object that i detected.

I wan't to know if the collider that was triggered is from the **Sight** Gameobject, **Detection** Gameobject or **Hearing** Gameobject.

Comment: So these are different `GameObjects` all using three different scripts which you didn't show us?

Comment: Not exactly. The GameObjects that i create dynamically are in the `Start`. (I ommited the *Detection* and *Hearing* because they aren't different.

They just have different radius.

These dynamic gameobjects don't have any script. Just the sphere collider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Unity is originally designed around a component based approach my approach would be to split up the three separate "detection" systems into separate GameObjects with their own collider and script.

- AliveEntity

  - SightController

    - ColliderA
  - DetectionController

    - ColliderB
  - HearingController

    - ColliderC

Then you can use the OnTrigger in each separate script to fire a notification to the main AbstractAliveEntity which then handles them on a case by case basis.

Main Script

```
OnSight(Collider other) {
  // Do sight related actions here
}

OnDetection(Collider other) {
  // Do detetction related actions here
}

OnHearing(Collider other) {
  // Do hearing related actions here
}
```

Then for each respetive detector:

```
// reference to master script
public AbstractAliveEntity aae;

OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
  // replace function with whatever you want to use
  aae.OnSight(other)
}
```

The Added advantage here is that you are now also free to design 'blind' or 'deaf' Entities without all too much hassle. (You simply do not add the respective components)

Comment: Awesome! That was my original idea. I wanted to design entities as abstract as possible. This point me out in the right direction, you nailed it thanks!

Comment: @Haytam95 glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

`other.gameObject` to get the gameObject the other collider is attached to.

Check unity documentation about collider [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks user601! What i want is to detect my own collider.

I've three colliders attached to childs objects. I want to know which of those colliders where triggered

Comment: Then it won't work like that .. `OnTriggerEnter` is called when a trigger enters a non-trigger collider .. yould have to make your entire setup exactly the other way round...